# Angular 2 mising traceur?

Tags: angular, traceur, rollupjs

I was following this tutorial on building a production version with rollup: http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/06/26/tree-shaking-angular2-production-build-rollup-javascript/

The production part is working well, but when I want to develop using `npm run start`(script which cleans the js directory, compiles the .ts files and watches for changes) the build fails with a `404` exceptin that sayes it failed to find 
`traceur`. The only difference that is notable is changing from `es5` and `commonjs` to `es2015` in the `tsconfig` file. How can I fix this to make the lite server work.

---

**error**

```
GET http://localhost:3000/traceur 404 (Not Found)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:1561
ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:242
Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:168
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1584
send @ VM1385:3
fetchTextFromURL @ system.src.js:1051
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:1781
ZoneAwarePromise @ zone.js:525
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:1780
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:2809
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:3387
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:3701
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:4093
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:4556
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:4825
(anonymous) @ system.src.js:407
ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:229
Zone.run @ zone.js:113
(anonymous) @ zone.js:509
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:262
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:151
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:405
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:336
(index):44 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
    Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:851:29) [<root>]
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47) [<root> => <root>]
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:332:33) [<root>]
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
    Unable to load transpiler to transpile http://localhost:3000/js/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/js/main.js
        at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as _onreadystatechange] (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:851:29) [<root>]
        at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:47) [<root> => <root>]
        at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:332:33) [<root>]
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/traceur
    Unable to load transpiler to transpile http://localhost:3000/js/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/js/main.js
```

---

**old_version**

```
{
   "compilerOptions":{
      "target":"ES5",
      "module":"commonjs",
      "moduleResolution":"node",
      "sourceMap":true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata":true,
      "experimentalDecorators":true,
      "removeComments":false,
      "noImplicitAny":false,
      "inlineSourceMap":false,
      "inlineSources":false,
      "outDir":"js"
   },
   "exclude":[
      "node_modules",
      "typings/main",
      "typings/main.d.ts"
   ],
   "compileOnSave":true
}
```

**new_version**

```
{
   "compilerOptions":{
      "target":"es2015",
      "module":"es2015",
      "moduleResolution":"node",
      "lib":[
         "es6",
         "es2015",
         "dom"
      ],
      "sourceMap":true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata":true,
      "experimentalDecorators":true,
      "removeComments":false,
      "noImplicitAny":false,
      "inlineSourceMap":false,
      "inlineSources":false,
      "outDir":"js",
      "typeRoots":[
         "./node_modules/@types",
         "./node_modules"
      ],
      "types":[

      ]
   },
   "exclude":[
      "node_modules",
      "typings/main",
      "typings/main.d.ts"
   ],
   "compileOnSave":true
}
```

**system.config.js**

```
/** * System configuration for Angular samples * Adjust as necessary for your application needs. */
(function(global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        map: {
            app: 'js',
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/router/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router-upgrade.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
            '@angular/upgrade/static': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade-static.umd.js',
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
            'primeng': 'npm:primeng',
            '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap': 'node_modules/@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/bundles/ng-bootstrap.js'
        },
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            primeng: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```